# Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure procedure name Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(1000);
SET @CurrentJuniferId =9456787763223
SET @s = 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.nbrSequence  START WITH ' +  
             CAST(@CurrentJuniferId AS bigint) + '
          INCREMENT BY 1 
          NO CYCLE' 

EXEC (@s)

SET @CurrentJuniferId
```

I am getting an error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_SEQuenceNbr_Allentities, Line 48 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: am getting error message as Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `@CurrentJuniferId` is not declared at all in your script, you use the "+" operator to "join" the string constants with the value of `@CurrentJuniferId`. The string datatypes have lower precedence than numeric ones and so the compiler attempts to convert your string constants to bigint (the datatype of your variable) and that fails. Much to learn here - suggest you ask your coworkers for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Error message tells you exactly what the issue is.

You've declared `@s` as a `nvarchar` yet you are trying to return a `bigint` from the select query. Instead of casting to bigint, cast to a `varchar`/ `nvarchar` instead.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL doesn't automatically convert numerical values to string, for string concatenation - that's up to you to do so.

So use this code instead:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @CurrentJuniferId BIGINT;

SET @CurrentJuniferId = 9456787763223

SET @s = N'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.nbrSequence ' +
         N'START WITH ' + CAST(@CurrentJuniferId AS NVARCHAR(20)) +               
         N'INCREMENT BY 1 NO CYCLE';
```

Comment: am getting error message as --select @EntityMinval,@EntityMaxval,@seqnamevar

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_SEQuenceNbr_Allentities, Line 65 [Batch Start Line 11]
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.